# Is there any benefit from installing 2 resistors in parallel instead of 1 resistor?

Tags: resistors, vacuum-tube

I'm restoring an old tube radio. When looking into the schematics I noticed that they drew 2 resistors in parallel instead of  1 resistor, between the power transformer and the rectifier tube. Is there any benefit from installing 2 parallel resistors instead one resistor?

Comment: Maybe the combined value was not available in a single resistor?

Comment: Also, you statistically get a better chance at being closer to the actual value you are looking for.

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25883/can-you-stack-smd-resistors-in-parallel-to-reduce-power-dissipation-per-resistor?rq=1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Two resistors have an increased ability to dissipate power/heat, up to twice the time one can, when mounted with enough space between them.

Also for a few applications it is easier to find two standard value resistors that together form one resistor value that is not among the standards you already have in your BOM (or are available).

Lastly for the gray beard hand chosen value resistor, it might have a higher yield to use two that are slightly off than to find the one that matches perfectly.

Comment: Is there also a possibility to reduce the effect of a failing resistor from a fatal fault to a fault which allows some sort of recovery or safe fault mechanism? In our designs we often have to put 2 resistors in series (not in parallel) to prevent a single failure to lead to a critical state, but each of the resistors must be able to handle all the power.

Comment: @Arsenal: It might be an added benefit, but I don't think it is the prime reason to initially add two resistors. When one fails short, the fault is still fatal. When one fails open, the resistance is doubled, but I can hardly imagine a scenario where this would not render a device as equally unusable as with a total open. If you design for safety, then you likely design for complete open or short, and anything in between is not going to be much better, possibly even worse.

Comment: I was curious, I had to check the pricing on this one. RS sells individual 1W resistors for 0.03GBP (bulk price is about half that.) they sell 10W resistors in 5-packs for 0.83GBP (bulk price is about half that.) So the saving is considerable, provided you don't take into account a nice large board to mount them on (which wouldn't be an additional requirement in the OP's case). Disclaimer: my prices are based on the cheapest available, with no consideration given to the resistance value.

Comment: @steveverrill: It would probably more realistic for the OPs case if you compared 500mW to 1W or similar, but yeah, I would subsume that all under "availability".

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Many vacuum devices are current-controlled rather than voltage-controlled, and are consequently more prone to damage if certain resistors fail open than if those same resistors fail shorted.

Comment: @supercat: Hm, how that? My main experience with tubes is to throw them away ^^

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Musicians pay big money (hundreds or thousands of dollars) for tube-type amplifiers these days.  I don't think I'd go that crazy for them, but I do think it's a neat technology and as with film it would be nice to keep it alive even if only for specialty purposes.

Comment: @supercat: Yeah, they also pay a lot for things like http://www.lessloss.com/blackbody-p-200.html but unless I want to sell in that market, I don't care. Still the question remains: how is an open fail worse than a half-the-current fail?

Comment: @PlasmaHH how about tolerance with 2 resistor would that change if each resistor has 5%

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Many tube circuits are supplied by voltages far in excess of what they're designed to work with.  Consider a tube which is intended to drive ~2mA into a 1k load at ~2 volts.  Remove the load resistor and it will feed ~2mA at 70+ volts.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ: do the math, tolerance will still be the same.

Comment: @PlasmaHH thanks wanted just to be sure, vote up dude

Comment: I installed both resistors in parallel, as per the schematics, but when I operated the radio both resistors became extremely hot so I put the radio off. Those resistors are installed in parallel and located between the main power transformer of the tube radio and the rectifier tube and their values are 270 ohms/2 watts and 330 ohms/2 watts. I've already changed all the bad capacitors, resistors and all 5 vacuum tubes. I've also done all the voltage checks and everything appears to be normal. What could be causing both resistors to heat-up?

Comment: @DMokdad: This ain't some discussion forum, so if you have a new question, please post a new one. Do some calculations first on what the design should disspiate there.

Answer (score 6):

The benefit is the power dissipation.

If you have a voltage V and a current I the power dissipation across a resistor is

$$ P=V \cdot I$$

Now if you put two resistors in parallel you divide the current in each resistor by 2 (if they have the same value) and then the power dissipated by 2.

Sometimes it is cheaper to put 2 resistors in parallel to dissipate more power than only one bigger resistor.

Comment: If you put two resistors in parallel in order to halve the power dissipation in each one, then you must increase the values of the paralleled resistors to twice that of the single resistor. BTW, it's \$"P=VI" \text{or}"P=EI" \text{,  not}"P=UI".\$

Comment: @EMFields U is a commonly used symbol for voltage in Germany at least, as there is no way to confuse it with V as Volt, so P=UI and U=RI over here.

Comment: @Arsenal: What's to confuse?  If V is voltage, then P=VI and V=RI.

Comment: @EMFields I guess they tried to prevent some confusion like V = 1 V so 0 = 0 or something like that. I don't know, it's just that on some parts of the world U is voltage so P = UI as well and it's hard to get away from stuff you are trained to use for years.

Comment: U is a pretty common symbol for a voltage variable in Brazil too.

Comment: @Arsenal it's still inconsistent with the rest of the post, where the voltage is referred to as V.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev that is true, I haven't checked the post thoroughly enough, only the comment from EM Fields which also contains P = EI (which would be inconsistent as well), so it sounded a bit like U was forbidden as a symbol for voltage.

Comment: Well, the math folks don't like why we insist on using _j_ for complex numbers instead of _i_. Standards are great; everyone should have one.

Comment: @EM Fields You're write it is just an error. I'm used to use U as voltage instead of V I edited the post

Comment: @Arsenal: 'E' has been used for a very long time as a symbol for Electromotive force, whih is measured in Volt(s). "V" is a more recent symbol representing Voltage directly and has been used interchangeably with 'E'  for many years. I can't imagine how 'U' managed to get into the picture unless it was a sloppily handwritten 'V' that no one questioned, but rather adopted it out of... who knows???

Comment: @EMFields some say it comes from Latin "urgeo" (push, force, drive), but the historical reason seems to be lost. Actually I've looked more into it and found that U is the formula symbol for a voltage as per DIN 1304-1:1994. Of course EE.SE is not bound by DIN EN ISO IPC or whatever standard, but people from all over the world will answer and thus every standard will be found in the answers. I encountered E for the first time during my electrodynamics lessons during my master which was held entirely in English.

Comment: @Arsenal: That works for me! :-)

Comment: @jdv Ironically, when you get into vectors in Cartesian coordinates, *j* (or rather, *ĵ*) conventionally corresponds to the usage of *i* when considering a complex plane while *î* corresponds to real numbers in a complex plane.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, the main reason increased is heat dissipation. I had a sound amplifier that had a huge power resistor which every week was burning out literally. One day I replaced it with 2 resistors and since then never failed.

Another experience of mine is regarding PCB design. I wanted to order minimum variety of components. So the pick and place machine won't charge me for extra rails. I had many 5k resistors in the design. Anywhere that I had 10k or 20k resistors I simply used 5k in series. A bit stupid but saved me few cents!