# Can you stack SMD resistors in parallel in a production run?

Tags: resistors, surface-mount

I am fighting part shortage issues.  I can't find a specific resistor value with a 1206 footprint for a set of boards we have been running.  I figured out that I can hit the resistance value with a pair of other resistors of the same footprint size.   I would modify the board, but every time the board is changed we have to send the job out for quote etc and it gets expensive for simple edits.  **I am wondering if we can just stack a pair of 1206 smd resistors.**  I am pretty sure we did this with caps once but I think they were connected to each other first before they were mounted to the board.  Would a board house be happy with this idea or there a way I can purchase the resistors pre-paired from DigiKey/mouser/Avent etc? This question is similar to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25883/can-you-stack-smd-resistors-in-parallel-to-reduce-power-dissipation-per-resistor) but not quite.

Comment: We are in the process of asking the board house, but I wanted to check with the community to see if there is something we are missing besides their response.

Comment: For the automated pick&place process the trouble you'll have is getting solder paste on top of the 1st part after it's been placed in order for the 2nd part to be able to solder down onto it. Doing that before reflow seems risky in that it might disturb the already placed part(s). After reflow would probably be les risky, but require manual soldering of the 2nd part on to the 1st. Either way is going to require some amount of manual work which would increase the cost.

Comment: Next time you have a passive where the value has to be really precise, give yourself a unpopulated footprint for another component placed in parallel.  Sometimes you might use a pair of resistors, other cases add a capacitor for filtering.  Unless you are trying to squeeze out every last mm-squared, the extra pads cost approximately zero if not used.

Comment: There are 192 values between 100 and 1K in the e192 series.  Be sure to figure out if  you can make spec with one of those values before running down the path of stacking.  I suspect even going with a 0.5% tolerance will be less expensive in terms of production.

Comment: The CM will happily do whatever you tell them, for a price.  My recommendation is to proceed with tacking on the resistor, and separately try to source the part you need (or try a different tolerance - or maybe even use an 0805 or 1210).  If you have exhausted all efforts to find a suitable part, then you may want to consider a respin of the PCB.

Comment: Have you considered using two smaller (e.g. 0603) resistors? Usually the pads are close enough, and you might just have enough width as well... To clarify, assembling two 0603 in place of a 1206 should be possible in many cases, with both resistors placed directly on the PCB. This would not require any special handling.

Comment: @VladimirCravero -- nice idea.  It  feels like standard pick and place should be able to handle that.  It would take some work with the production files, but that would be all NRE's, and kill the need for hand work.

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee it works. I have seen production boards in the wild using exactly this technique - while I can't be sure they were fully machine assembled, I am pretty close to sure :)

Comment: I was able resolve the issue by finding a .05% tolerance resistor which was the wrong value, but was within the tolerance window.  Thank you everyone for the helpful responses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a similar issue and had to ask the same question to my manufacturer.
This is possible but it's a manual operation, so the cost increase is non-negligible (and I limited it to as few units as possible on my side).

Answer (score 5):

Most manufactures will do this kind of work, it will end up being a hand solder and probably cost extra. I have had to do this once and I used a local board manufacturer. I have seen stacked capacitors (and they are very expensive). If you wanted to do this you could probably find a company to stack resistors for you in the same way the capacitors are made at a horrible NRE, but it would probably be easier to redesign. (so unless you have a special use case, like volume restriction I would go with a hand solder step)

Answer (score 4):

Given that hand-mods are horribly expensive, stacking two resistors is probably about the cheapest hand-mod you can use. The first resistor there provides a nice unambiguous location, and nice solder fillets to drag up.

Forget trying to buy them ready-stacked. They won't go through the standard placement machine.

The normal problem with 'can I use two resistors?' of heat dissipation should not be a problem here, as you have already designed for one 1206 resistor, had you been able to get it.

Answer (score 2):

You should contact higher end part manufacturers (Vishay, KOA, Ohmite, TE) directly and see if they can provide you with the value you need. Sometimes they offer reels of weird values (not in the Exx series), specifically trimmed for customers.

Comment: Do be aware you'll either be paying extra, or have higher MOQs, for such a service.

Comment: Of course, there is no such thing as free lunch. One SMD resistor is more reliable than a stack of 2.

Answer (score 2):

If your fab house has an automated rework machine, there is a chance that it could be coerced into doing this.

Specifically the MSEng MS7600 supports parts down to 0402, and it has enough z travel to clear some fairly tall connectors when we last specced it.
MSEng's support is fairly responsive if you want to shoot them a question about it.

Also you should switch to a no-stencil solder paste machine and ask it to throw some extra on those pads if you can. There should be enough goober left after reflow to give you a workable joint on the second resistor.

It's definitely a bad idea, but a good fab house will give a bad idea a shot :)

http://www.mseng.co.jp/new/en/products/rework/ms7600.html

Comment: Feels like there would be very high NRE costs.